# Conditional statement in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, conditional-statements

I need a helping hand. I got a little lost in my code to set up a condition.
Basically I want to set up a checkbox that will look for the stock of a product. My array of product information is stored in this.state.displayArray.
If the product is in stock, so if this.state.displayArray.stock> 0 the checkbox is checked.

actually it sounds simple like that and i think it is but i need a little helping hand to make sure i do it right, I don't know where to add the condition, in the function or directly in the checkbox.

Thanks for your help.

```
export default class Stock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {      
      stock : true,
    }
  };

    initListData = async () => {
    let list = await getProducts(1);
   
    if (list) {
      this.setState({
        displayArray: list,
        loadMoreVisible: (list.length >= 15 ? true : false),
        currentPage: 2
      });
      console.log(this.state.displayArray)
    } 
  };

    async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initListData();
    console.log(this.state.displayArray)    
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View pointerEvents="none" style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <CheckBox
            value={this.state.stock}
          />
          <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}>Stock</Text>
        </View>
      </View> 
      );
    }
  }
```

displayArray: (for now it's a flight but it will change, I have someone working on API)

```
Array [   Object {
    "cost": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-12-14T15:54:50Z",
    "custom_fields": Object {
      "_161_": "4137",
      "_162_": "48",
      "_163_": "10926",
      "_164_": "0",
      "_165_": "FLY",
      "_166_": "2020-12-14T14:54:37.737Z",
      "_167_": "2020-12-31T14:54:37.737Z",
      "_168_": "0",
      "_171_": "0",
      "_300_": "412:00",
      "_301_": "45.725556|5.081111",
      "_302_": "-27.7078990936|-67.0951004028",
      "_303_": "Lyon Saint-Exupéry Airport",
      "_304_": "Londres/Belén Airport",
      "_310_": "60",
    },
    "description": "",
    "family_id": 0,
    "id": 1061,
    "incl_tax": 0,
    "is_visible": 1,
    "name": "Lyon Saint-Exupéry Airport (14/12/2020 à 15:54) > Londres/Belén Airport (31/12/2020 à 15:54)",
    "photo": "",
    "quantity": 0,
    "reference": "",
    "stock_status": "1",
    "tax_rate_id": 0,
    "unit": "",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-14T15:54:50Z",
    "weight": 0,   },   Object {
    "cost": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-11-15T01:38:08Z",
    "custom_fields": Object {
      "_161_": "1373",
      "_162_": "30",
      "_163_": "4680",
      "_164_": "0",
      "_165_": "FLY",
      "_166_": "2020-11-21T00:37:00.000Z",
      "_167_": "2020-11-29T00:37:00.000Z",
      "_168_": "0",
      "_171_": "0",
      "_300_": "190:00",
      "_301_": "43.6539083949|-79.65785399079999",
      "_302_": "-22.285699844399996|-62.7136993408",
      "_303_": "Tarten Heliport",
      "_304_": "Santa Victoria Airport",
      "_310_": "-480",
    },
    "description": "",
    "family_id": 0,
    "id": 896,
    "incl_tax": 0,
    "is_visible": 1,
    "name": "Tarten Heliport (2020-11-21 at 16:37) > Santa Victoria Airport (2020-11-29 at 16:37)",
    "photo": "",
    "quantity": 0,
    "reference": "",
    "stock_status": "1",
    "tax_rate_id": 0,
    "unit": "FLY",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-15T01:38:08Z",
    "weight": 0,   }, ]
```

Comment: How did you import `CheckBox`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I used : "import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox'; "

Comment: Can you add what does `displayArray` contain, please?

Comment: Yes, I add it to my post. :) That's really nice of you to help me.

Comment: First of all, displayArray is an array and you can't call `this.state.displayArray.stock` also objects in this array don't contain `stock` key.

Comment: it's stock_status sorry

Comment: Anyway, it's incorrect. this.state.displayArray.stock doesn't exist, you can call `this.state.displayArray[1].stock` etc.